# Почему выдает ошибку в консоли? js

Tags: javascript, html5

Столкнулся с ошибкой в консоли:

> Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined

Не пойму почему она возникает. Подскажите, пожалуйста.
Вот пример где она возникает:

```js
var choice = document.getElementsByClassName('choice');
for(var i = 0; i <= choice.length; i++){
    choice[i].onclick = choosePar;
}
function choosePar(){
    if(this.value == 'y'){
        console.log('yes');
    }
    if(this.value == 'n'){
        console.log('not');
    }
}
```

```html
<button class="choice" value="y">Да</button>
<button class="choice" value="n">Нет</button>
```

Comment: зачем вы дали атрибут `value` тегу `button` ?

Comment: в цикле не меньше или равно, а просто меньше **i < choice.length**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не корректное условие в цикле. Надо так `for(var i = 0; i < choice.length; i++)`. Не `<=`, а `<`. Если бы с `1` начал, то `<=`

Также не забывай про `onload` и `domready`

Answer (score 0):

choice.length - кол-во элементов, в данном случае их 2, но массивы нумеруются с нуля. Т.е. у вас есть элементы с индексами 0 и 1 Вы делаете цикл с 0 до 2 включительно, и он перебирает 0, 1, 2. Когда вы обращаетесь к choice[2] - вы получаете undefined, а у него нет свойства onClick, что и выдаёт данную ошибку в консоли